# Microsoft Access - Using a form to input data into a different table with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Trying to use a form named 'Customer Entry', that when clicked, enters the data that has been typed in said form into a table that is named 'CustomerRecord'. I keep getting errors and am at my wits end. Here is my code below, this is in VBA.

```
Public Sub Command19_Click() 
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO CustomerRecord(Customer Name, APM, UAID, Context Code, Purpose Code, Context Description, Purpose Description) " & _
" VALUES (" & Me.txtCustomer Name & ", " & Me.txtAPM & ", " & Me.txtUAID & ", " & Me.txtContextCode & "," & Me.txtPurposeCode & ", " & Me.txtContext Description & ", " & Me.txtPurpose Description & ")"
frmCustomer 
     Entry.Form.Requery 
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not set the Record Source for the form to the CustomerRecord table, and the Control Source for the controls to the fields within the table?  No coding needed.

Comment: Also thinking `Me.txtCustomer Name` should be `Me.txtCustomer_Name` - replace the spaces with underscores.

Comment: The field names should also not contain spaces in the SQL string. `Customer Name` should be `[Customer Name]`. And string values should be wrapped in single quotes `'abc'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit data from two tables on a single form you need to make an updatable query to base your form upon. Set your forms `RecordSource` property to be the updatable query. Now you can add form elements from the source that allow the user to edit all the fields directly.

See this list of pitfalls to ensure that your query is updatable:
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html

If you absolutely must edit data elsewhere from your form, which you occasionally must do, don't use an SQL query execute statement to do so. Use a recordset object instead. This is both more secure, more reliable, and easier to read the code.

See this guide for an example of how it's done: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Data-Access-Objects/modify-an-existing-record-in-a-dao-recordset

Additional reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-edit-method-dao